# Debian server can't connect to outside world and vice versa

Tags: apache-2.2, networking, debian, kvm-virtualization

At some point within the past 48 hours my KVM server, which had been running without issue for 6 months, went down completely and was unreachable. Using the control panel to my server, I saw that the server was in fact offline. I got in touch with my host and they weren't able to provide me with any information at all. I rebooted the server, and tried to connect to the IP address and other sites hosted, and wasn't able to. Whether using a browser or nslookup, the connection would time out.

I accessed the virtualization via VNC, and gained access to the machine. All my files and everything else seem to be in order, and the machine doesn't seem to have been accessed by anyone else but me.

Pinging the server IP and domain names alike, result in a timed out connection. From the server's terminal, I am getting servfail errors when I try to `nslookup` or `dig` an outside IP.

```
nslookup google.com
;; GOT SERVFAIL reply from 127.0.0.1, trying next server
Server:         ::1
Address:        ::1#53

** server can't find google.com: SERVFAIL



dig google.com
; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-9+deb8u3-Debian <<>> google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: Query, status: SERVFAIL, id: 40939
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp:4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com

;; Query time: 53 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Thu Jan 21 16:54:54 EST 2016
;; MSG SIZE rcvd: 39
```

I also can't access the internet via the virtualization on a browser.

I can lookup 127.0.0.1 just fine though. So I think it might be a networking issue, but frankly, I'm at a loss, and I don't know what to do.

Any help at all would be appreciated.

EDIT:

```
ifconfig -a
eth0    Link encap:Ethernet HWadder 00:16:3c:46:e9b0
        inet6 addr: fe80::216:3cff:fe46:e9b0/64 Scope:Link
        UP BROADCASTING RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
        RX packets:1054844 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
        RX bytes:65592375 (62.5MiB)  TX bytes:80043 (78.1 KiB)

lo      Link encap:Local Loopback
        inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
        inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
        UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
        RX packets:996 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
        TX packets:996 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
        RX bytes:85328 (83.3 KiB)  TX bytes:85328 (83.3 KiB)
```

`route -n`
`Destination    Gateway    Genmask    Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

`arp -n` returns no result.

EDIT 2:

```
/etc/network/interfaces

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Comment: You need to add (to begin with) the output from `ifconfig -a`, `arp -n`, and `route -n`.

Comment: @Law29 Sure, one moment. I have to write these by hand since I can't copy and paste. Briefly, I will say that both eth0 and lo seem to be running without issue. `arp -n` returns no result.

Comment: Your eth0 interface has not been configured with a global IP address. How was it supposed to be configured? Where is `/etc/network/interfaces`?

Comment: How come it doesn't have an IP4 address under eth0? My server has "inet addr:10.x.x.x" above the inet6 addr line. This seems like something worth investigating, unless you just haven't copied it in.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Added the interfaces

Comment: @Tim Good question. I'll look into that.

Comment: DHCP? That's rather unusual. Your hypervisor generally should have a static address configured.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I've tried removing the line completely, and simply using `auto eth0`, response seems to be the same. I'm going to attempt giving it a static IP address.

Comment: If your hoster wants your machine to be provisioned with DHCP, then that is what you should do, but make sure that is what your hoster actually says. If it is so, then there should be useful logs from the DHCP service. I forgot to ask you for the output of `ethtool eth0 | grep Link`.

Answer (score 0):

as Michael Hampton your eth0 interface is configured to get IP address information via [DHCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol).

Normally you would need to configure your network interface manually or static.

An example would look like this in you /etc/network/interfaces config file

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.0.2.7
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.0.2.254
```

More information could be found in the debian documentation.[2](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration)

So check with your server hoster what IP address, netmask and gateway your server should have. Sometimes you can get the information out of the customer portal.
As soon as you have this data configure your network interface accordingly.

Regards

-- arl